# django dev to deployment

Tags: authentication, ssh

ssh root@my_server_ip
Created a new user with following comman:
adduser djangoadmin
usermod -aG sudo djangoadmin
Add SSH key for new user

cd /home/djangoadmin
mkdir .ssh
cd .ssh
nano authorized_keys

Paste the key and hit "ctrl-x", hit "y" to save and "enter" to exit

But when i Login as new user

ssh djangoadmin@YOUR_SERVER_IP

i had such error:

C:\Users\User>ssh djangoadmin@142.93.107.127
djangoadmin@142.93.107.127: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: to go into the root i used before this:

Comment: ssh -i C:\Users\User\.ssh\id_rsa_do root@142.93.107.127